# Why isn't my pomegranate tree bearing fruit?

Tags: fruit-trees, pomegranate, fruit-drop

I have a good size pomegranate tree I planted in the ground about 6 years ago. The plant is healthy and bears flowers and tiny fruit which quickly fall off rather than developing into a good size pomegranate. I get fruit later in the year but only a handful. I hear similar complaints from neighbors.

What am I doing wrong?
What is the fruiting season in zone 9b?

[image]

[image]

Comment: same here,.. except the plant is smaller than shown above.. please help

Comment: What usda zone are you in?

Comment: we might be neighbors ;-) same as you, 9b.

Comment: So, what is your local pollinator situation? Bees are having a hard time in many places, and as a result, we do too. You can try providing habitat for alternative pollinators (mason bees, etc.) and you can try doing it yourself for the blossoms you can reach...

Comment: What was the weather like when the plant was in bloom?

Comment: Weather varied from 60 to 100 degrees.  Note that this fruit drop happens every year.  I get some fruits late season (sept, oct)

Comment: @Ecnerwal  do you think pollination is an issue?  I do have bees and as you can see the fruit starts forming and then drops (2nd picture).